# Javac ignores first line of sourcepath file and doesn't compile class

Tags: java, shell, compilation, javac

I have a project with such structure (shortened for simplicity):

[image]

and I'm trying to compile it with terminal.

I'm in `src` directory and firstly doing this:

```
find * -name "*.java" > sources.txt
```

After the first command a `sources.txt` file is generated:

```
aircraft/Baloon.java
aircraft/Aircraft.java
aircraft/JetPlane.java
aircraft/AircraftFactory.java
aircraft/Coordinates.java
aircraft/Flyable.java
aircraft/Helicopter.java
exception/WrongNumberArgsException.java
simulator/Simulator.java
```

Further I'm doing:

```
javac -sourcepath @sources.txt
```

And it generates all `.class` files, EXCEPT the first one - `Baloon.java` is totally ignored by javac.

If I do:

```
javac -sourcepath @sources.txt src/aircraft/Baloon.java
```

a `Baloon.class` file is generated as well with other `.class` files.

If I manually change first row of `sources.txt`, for example switch first and second rows, then when I recompile again first `.java` file in `sources.txt` is ignored by javac and respective `.class` file is not created.

Alternatively if I compile with Intellij Idea - everything is fine, no problems occur.

It doesn't matter if I compile in the root directory of project, or in `src` directory, result is the same - first line of `sources.txt` is ignored.

So the question is - what I'm doing wrong with above 2 terminal commands? or maybe it's a bug of javac?

javac version - 1.8.0_221

project files themself: https://github.com/Dman-89/42_avaj_launcher

Comment: I'm amazed that specifying `-sourcepath @sources.txt` makes any difference at all, since the documentation of [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) says that the source path is a list of *"**directories**, JAR archives, or ZIP archives"*. Since there are none of those listed, the list might as well be empty, i.e. you might as well not give the `-sourcepath` option.

Comment: @Andreas, it must be really a bug of javac - removing `-sourcepath` option indeed helped - now ALL files were compiled to `.class` files.

Comment: The default *sourcepath* is the same as the *classpath*, and the default *classpath* is `.`, i.e. the current directory. When you explicitly specify a *sourcepath*, the current directory is no longer on the path, so now the compiler cannot find the other source files. The bug is yours, not the compilers.

Comment: @Andreas, nevertheless, compiler does find ALL except one source files (first line of `sources.txt` file) - it finds (and compiles), among others, all the rest files in the same directory, where `Baloon.java` is situated - that's weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your aim is to create a list of source files, and then pass them all to javac to compile. If that is your aim, `-sourcepath` is not what you want.

You want one of two things:

### Do what all real java programmers do

'real' defined as: They do it for money and/or eyeballs, and not as an academic exercise.

Use a build system; gradle or maven are the common choices. They will take care of all this for you far better than a slapdash effort to hack some bash scripts together.

### Just pass the java source files

Just remove the `-sourcepath` part. `javac @sources.txt` is what you want.

### What is going on?

The first 'argument' (first line in your `sources.txt` file) is the 'value' for the `-sourcepath` argument, and javac doesn't compile this, because `-sourcepath` doesn't mean 'compile this stuff' (see later). The rest (lines 2 and further) are just arguments, which is *actually* what javac will compile.

### So what is sourcepath?

To compile source files with javac, you'd write `javac foo/A.java bar/B.java`. However, what if, say, `A.java` contains: `import lombok.Value;`? Javac is now not capable of compiling this file unless javac knows about `lombok.Value`. Usually such dependencies are already compiled (you have class files in a directory or a jar file), in which case you'd use the `-classpath` option of `javac` to tell javac about where to find this stuff.

`-sourcepath` is similar, except, it's for not-yet-compiled stuff. That means javac will gain awareness of the existence of anything in the sourcepath, in case it comes up that any of that needs to be compiled first, **and will only do so if it is needed by any of the actual files you specified for compilation**.

Like any `-xpath` option to `javac` or `java`, if you want to specify more than 1 entry, use colons (semicolons on windows) as a separator, not space. Furthermore, the idea is to pass directories and not actual files. And just like `-classpath`, passing invalid (e.g. non-existing) paths is fine. Then they are just ignored.

### Example

```
javac -sourcepath deps:deps2 src/com/mypkg/Main.java src/com/mypkg/Extra.java
```

This will tell javac to compile Main and Extra (not `deps` or `deps2` or any files inside). However, if, say, `Main.java` contains the line: `Object o = new bar.baz.Hello();`, *and* the file `deps/bar/baz/Hello.java` exists, then this command will end up also compiling `Hello.java`. If `deps/bar/baz/Whatever.java` also exists, that won't be compiled, unless `Whatever` is mentioned somewhere in `Hello.java`, `Main.java`, or `Extra.java`. And not in either a comment or just an import statement (`import` if java-ese for `alias`, it doesn't actually import anything).

Comment: I agree, that gradle/maven would do this task better, but "academic exercise" requires me to compile in terminal, as our grandfathers did=)

Answer (score 1):

`javac` will compile the source files specified, e.g. just `Baloon.java` in your case.

In addition, any classes referenced from those explicitly named source files will also be compiled, if the compiler can find the source files for them. It looks for them on the *sourcepath*, which defaults to the same as the *classpath* if not specified.

Assuming `Simulator` is the class with the `main()` method (as indicated by the green "play" triangle of the icon), it will directly or indirectly reference all the other source files, so that's the file to specify:

```
cd src
javac simulator/Simulator.java
```

Or:

```
javac -cp src src/simulator/Simulator.java
```

Comment: nice alternative with single file for `javac` - upvote=)